# How to remove lexer in qscintilla

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

How can I remove a lexer in qscintilla that I have set with.setLexer(lexer) if the user wants to go back to plain text? I have not found anything in the [documentation](http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/ports-1.5a-CURRENT/devel/qscintilla2/work/QScintilla-1.73-gpl-2.1/doc/html-Qt4/classQsciScintilla.html#258109e2ba67bb8ab2102cbc66abe683). I'm using PyQt5 with Python3.

Comment: `setLexer(None)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro i tested it and it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as @ekumoro replied in the comment above and it is working pretty fine.

> self.__editor.setLexer(None)

https://scintilla.sourceforge.io/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETLEXER
[image]

Comment: The `setLexer` slot is part of the QScintilla API and the docs for it are [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciScintilla.html#a7bc5fb5d0daf8261544fb6fe738a0c91). The `SCI_SETLEXER` message is part of the underlying Scintilla API, and it does not do the same thing.

Comment: u'r right ... thanks for the link
however, the API names are close